# formvalidation.io - how to skip validating empty fields?

Tags: javascript, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I have a form with the following element:

```
<input type="number" />
```

When using `formvalidation.io` upon form submission that field **always** gets validated (to make sure that only digits are allowed) and as a result `.has-success` class is added to its parent.

Question. How do I tell `formvalidation.io` to never validate empty fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove `notEmpty`

```
'TelephoneNumber': {
                        validators: {
                            //notEmpty: {
                            //    message: 'Please enter Telephone number only'
                            //},
                            digits: {
                                message: 'Only digits accepted'
                            },

                         },
```